# Unable to fetch available regions for service watson-vision-combined

Tags: ibm-watson

I am trying to create a project in Visual Recognition in IBM Watson Studio. I am from India. I am in lite version and the region is London (default) as India was not there.

When I am trying to create it, it's showing me this error :
An error occurred.

Unable to fetch available regions for service watson-vision-combined

What do I need to do ?

I tried using VPN but still the same error.

Comment: GET request to https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/studio/api/redirect/regions?service_label=watson-vision-combined gives an Internal server error (500). Its better to create a support ticket. Error response ({"message":"Error fetching service: Error: [Failed][Request #865] Encountered runtime error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND globalcatalog. globalcatalog.:443"})